# Modifying Data Frame structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, tm

I need help with restructuring my data frame.

I currently have the following data structure:
[Current data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNABM.png)

I need to get to this :

```
post 229 comments 220 badge 209 washington 160
```

Notice that I do not need the serial numbers or the column names. I only need the word and the frequency posted adjacent to it. Any package will do.

Answer (score 2):

```
paste(df$WORD, df$FREQ, sep=" ")
```

Comment: Maybe rather `paste(df$WORD, df$FREQ, collapse=" ")`?

Answer (score 0):

Set `row.names=FALSE` in `print` statement, better to write it out with `row.names=FALSE`and `col.names=FALSE` into an output file

```
df <- data.frame(WORD=c("post","comments","badge","washington"),FREQ=c(229,220,209,160))
print (df, row.names=FALSE)  # You have to use print 

# Creating dataframe without column names
df <- data.frame(c("post","comments","badge","washington"),c(229,220,209,160))
```

You can directly write it out as below:

```
 write.table(df,file="MyFile.txt",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,sep="\t")
```

Comment: This would have been perfect if I knew the exact words and frequencies. However, I do not have that information and hence need a more generic code. I used rbind to restructure the data and it worked perfectly. I am sorry for the confusion, should have been more clear while posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help but I figured it out. I had to use the command rbind.

Here is my code:

```
#Bind the matrix together
result <- matrix(rbind(df[,1],ft[,2]))
#Transpose the binded matrix to get desired shape
FreqTerms <- t(result)
```